# Calculating the matrix derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial X}||CX^{-1}B||_F^2$

Tags: matrices, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

For matrices $C, X$, and $B$, I know that $\frac{\partial}{\partial X}||CXB||_F^2 = 2C^TCXBB^T$, and that $\partial X^{-1} = -X^{-1}(\partial X) X^{-1}$. However, I am unable to combine these results to calculate $\frac{\partial}{\partial X}||CX^{-1}B||_F^2$.

Comment: And what happens if you try to apply the chain rule? Do you get something that you know is wrong, or it just looks very complicated and you are not convinced you are correct? (Or, are you having a confusion with the chain rule itself?)

Comment: I'm not aware of how the chain rule generalizes to matrix derivatives.

Comment: I see. But you have seen matrix derivatives, is that right? So I would not need to introduce it if I were to write an answer.

Comment: Yes, I understand what a matrix derivative is.

Comment: Thanks, I will write an answer(sorry for the delay, I was busy in work).

Comment: Ok, here is a clarification, just to be absolutely sure : if you know how matrix derivatives work, can you explain what is $\frac{\partial}{\partial X} \|CXB\|_F^2$ as a linear transformation? What is its domain, codomain and how does it act upon a given matrix?

Comment: The way I'm thinking about it is the operator $\frac{\partial}{\partial X}||CXB||_F^2$ acts as $X \mapsto  2C^TCXBB^T$, with domain $M^{n \times n}$ and the matrices in the codomain have columns in the column space of $CC^T$ and rows in the columns space of $B^TB$.

Comment: Great, that is correct, so I will write an answer. Note I have upvoted your question.

Comment: Thank you for the acceptance, I hope I will help you more in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a new matrix variable
$$\eqalign{
 Y &= X^{-1} \qquad\implies\qquad
dY &= -Y\,dX\,Y \\
}$$
Use the gradient, which you already know, to write the *differential* of the function in terms of $Y$
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \|CYB\|^2 \\
d\phi &= 2\Big(C^TCYBB^T\Big):dY \\
}$$
Then perform a change of variables from $Y\to X$
$$\eqalign{
d\phi
 &= 2\Big(C^TCYBB^T\Big):\Big(-Y\,dX\,Y\Big) \\
 &= -2\Big(Y^TC^TCYBB^TY^T\Big):dX \\
 &= -2\Big((X^{-1})^TC^TCX^{-1}BB^T(X^{-1})^T\Big):dX \\
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial X}
 &= -2(X^{-1})^TC^TCX^{-1}BB^T(X^{-1})^T \\
}$$

---

In the above, a colon is used as a product notation for the trace, i.e.
$$\eqalign{A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB) = {\rm Tr}(B^TA) = B:A}$$
The terms in such a product can be rearranged in a number of equivalent ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
A:BC &= B^TA:C = AC^T:B \\
}$$
due to the properties of the trace function.

As you have discovered, the chain rule is difficult to apply in Matrix Calculus. It often requires the calculation of intermediate quantities which are third and fourth order tensors.

The beauty of the differential approach is that the differential of a matrix *acts like a matrix*. In particular, it obeys all of the rules of matrix algebra.

Answer (score 2):

For ease of typing, let's define $$ F = CX^{-1}B$$

Its differential is given by: $$dF  = (dC)X^{-1}B + C(dX^{-1})B + CX^{-1}(dB)$$

We have $dA=0$, $dB=0$, and we can calculate $dX^{-1}$ as follows :

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
X^{-1}X & = I \\
\implies dX^{-1}X + X^{-1}dX & = dI = 0 \\
\implies dX^{-1}X & = - X^{-1}dX \\
\implies dX^{-1} & = - X^{-1}(dX)X^{-1} \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Back to our expression, we have,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
Y &= ||F||_F^2 \\
& = \text{Tr}(F^TF) = F:F \\
\implies dY & = dF:F + F:dF \\
& = F:dF + F:dF \\
& = 2F:dF \\
& = 2CX^{-1}B:C(dX^{-1})B \\
& = 2CX^{-1}B:-CX^{-1}(dX)X^{-1}B \\
& = -2(CX^{-1})^TCX^{-1}B:(dX)X^{-1}B \\
& = -2(CX^{-1})^TCX^{-1}B(X^{-1}B)^T:dX \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Finally, we get:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial (CX^{-1}B)}{\partial X} &= -2(CX^{-1})^TCX^{-1}B(X^{-1}B)^T\\
&= -2(X^{-1})^TC^TCX^{-1}BB^T(X^{-1})^T
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

The function $X \to \|CX^{-1}B\|_F^2$ is a composition of the functions $g(X)= X^{-1}$ followed by $f(Y) = \|CYB\|_F^2$.

The crux of the multidimensional derivative is the following : for $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ differentiable everywhere, the derivative $f'$ is an association such that for any $y \in \mathbb R^n$, $f'(y) : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ is a linear transformation (hence a matrix), which is given by $$
f'(y)v = \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{f(y+tv) - f(y)}{t} 
$$

Therefore, noting that $M_{n \times n}$ may also be equated to a space $\mathbb R^{n^2}$ in our explanation above, we have $f : M_{n \times n} \to \mathbb R$, hence $f'(Y)$ for any $Y \in M_{n \times n}$ is a linear transformation from $M_{n \times n} \to \mathbb R$. According to what you have derived, we have :
$$
[f'(Y)]M = 2C^TCYBB^TM
$$

Similarly, $g(X) = X^{-1}$ is a function from $M_{n \times n} \to M_{n \times n}$, so $g'(Y)$ for any $Y \in M_{n \times n}$ is a linear transformation from $M_{n \times n} \to M_{n \times n}$ given by :
$$
[g'(Y)]N = -Y^{-1}NY^{-1}
$$

---

The chain rule tells you that the derivative of $f \circ g$ is :
$$
[f \circ g]'(X) = f'(g(X)) \cdot g'(X)
$$

where $\cdot$ indicates matrix multiplication (or composition of the linear transformations which are the derivatives).

In particular, for any $M$ we have :
$$
[[f \circ g]'(X)]M = f'(g(X)) [[g'(X)]M]
$$

Note that if $f \circ g$ is well defined then this matrix multiplication will also go through without a dimension problem.

---

In our case, we have $[g'(X)]M =  -X^{-1}MX^{-1}$, and finally, we get that $$
[[f \circ g]'(X)](M) = f'(g(X))[g'(X)M] = -2C^TCX^{-1}BB^TX^{-1}M X^{-1}
$$

is how the derivative acts as a linear map at each $M \in M_{n \times n}$.

Comment: @Powerspawn Was there a doubt you had on the question? Because I saw that you had made a comment and then it got deleted before I could read it.

Comment: Thank you for this. I do have another question, it's my understanding that as a matrix, $\frac{\partial f(X)}{\partial X}(M) = [ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{ji}}]_{ij}(M)$. Is it possible to represent $-2C^TCX^{-1}BB^TX^{-1}M X^{-1}$ in the form $AM$ for some matrix $A$?

Comment: @Powerspawn The expression $-2C^TCX^{-1}BB^TX^{-1}MX^{-1}$ is going to be a real number for each matrix $M$. If I multiply $M$ by a matrix $A$, the quantity $AM$ is not going to be a real number, so I don't think this is possible : in fact, the general non-commutativity of matrices means that you can't bring that last $X^{-1}$ to the left of the $M$.

Comment: @Powerspawn I should also add something : the derivative $f'(X) = 2C^CXBB^T$ is actually somewhat incorrect. The correct expression is $[f'(X)](M) = 2tr(C^TCXBB^TM)$, but we leave out the trace if the argument is a scalar. We can't do that in general, of course : accordingly I will modify the above answer.

Comment: The definition for the matrix derivative that I was using is that $\frac{\partial f(X)}{\partial X}$ is the $n \times n$ matrix with $(i,j)$th entry equal to $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{ji}}$. I believe according to this definition $\frac{\partial}{\partial X}||CXB||_F^2 = 2C^TCXBB^T$ should be correct.

Comment: @Powerspawn That makes sense too, but in this case to match the dimensions, we must take the trace. Anyway, in that case I won't modify the answer ; the key point is the chain rule and the fact that linear operators on matrices won't always be right multiplication by a matrix but could end up being complicated.

Comment: That makes sense to me, as there are only $n^2$ parameters that can be used to represent a linear operator as left-multiplication by a matrix, and $n^4$ parameters that can be used to describe a general linear transformation of a matrix. But I suppose the thing that is still confusing me is that according to the definition I'm using, $\frac{\partial}{\partial X}||CX^{-1}B||_F^2 $ is the matrix with $(i,j)$th entry equal to $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{ji}}||CX^{-1}B||_F^2$, and computing this matrix is my main goal. I am still not quite sure how I can do that.

Comment: @Powerspawn In that case (if you are computing that matrix), we shall have to proceed by definition . Let me look at this and edit my answer (by 4-5 hours an edit should be up).